# Possible to use an older tablet with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen

I have an older tablet with a single touch monitor laying around.  Is possible to use the touch features of windows 8 with this older touch technology?

Will I lose a significant amount of functionality by not having a multitouch capable monitor?

Comment: Might help to state *how*  old this is and what it runs now. Better yet, state what the tablet is.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek:  Its a thinkpad X61

Comment: You said it was HP ;p

Comment: Doh!  Sorry, edited the original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amusingly, someone's [done it before](http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=102695), actually, this seems really common looking at [google.](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%208%20x61&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb)

Apparently the more common version of the X61 uses a digitiser pen - and using the desktop with [it seems tricky](http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=102695) since its harder to hover over an area. And yes, its common enough that there are youtube videos of people using [windows 8 on an x61](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74oo4h9yM-0).

I think you can decide if its worth the effort based off all this - It *might* work for you, but it is unlikely to be as easy as a 'real' touchscreen or a mouse.

Comment: Its Monday morning, and my google-fu appears to be just as down as my MDT server.  Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't suggesting you didn't look. And I certainly wasn't going to leave it at 'LMGFY'. This was actually pretty cool to learn about ^^

Answer (score 2):

It should work but it is likely it will simply emulate a mouse (as that was the usual workaround for Windows having no real support) rather than be a "true" touchscreen as Windows 8 would expect.

The features you would lose are mostly gestures such as swiping and dragging to move the screen around or provide extra options, and you would not be able to use pinch to zoom.

Comment: Any explanation as to why it will emulate a mouse vs. act like a touchscreen?

Answer (score 0):

I have personally attempted to use it with a Dell Latitude XT. The core OS works, as well as the digitizer - however I could not get multi-touch working.

I am afraid to run the official (Dell or ntrig) drivers as they are known to flash firmware and fail (as least has been my experiences). This can at worst brick the digitizer - best case reinstall the OS and try again. There are tools floating around to restore the digitizer, but I don't want to risk it.

I have toyed with the idea of installing it on a Compaq TC1000 just to see what it will do.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the touchscreen are based on TUIO framework and they generate TUIO events on touch so you can use [EcoTUIODriver](https://github.com/ecologylab/EcoTUIODriver) by Interface Ecology Lab on your windows 8 machine , this will generate the native windows 8 touch events .